# Word count by a category in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a column with text reviews, and another column with ratings:

```
Content                Rating

"bluetooth is bad"          1

"head unit crashes"         2

"remote works awesome"      5
```

I want to input a set of keywords, and count their occurrence in the comments, by the different ratings.

Put simply, to find out what the different people (rating defines the cohort) mention the most.

```
Rating    Word    Count

1     bluetooth   1

1     head unit   0

1     remote      0

2     bluetooth   0

2     head unit   1

2     remote      0

5     bluetooth   0

5     head unit   0

5     remote      1
```

I am coding after many years, and frankly I was trying to write a function but I have too many syntactical errors.

Comment: You should give a better example of your data frame and an example of the expected output.

Comment: Dataset looks like:
Content Rating
bluetooth is bad 1
head unit crashes 2
remote works awesome 5

word list <- c("bluetooth","headunit","remote")

Desired output:
Rating Word Count
1 bluetooth 1
1 head unit 0
1 remote 0
2 bluetooth 0
2 head unit 1
2 remote 0
5 bluetooth 0
5 head unit 0
5 remote 1

Comment: can you format that in the question?

Comment: use `dput` function on your data and add the result to your question so that others can recreate it easily

Comment: just edited the question, hoping it helps

Comment: @Kristofersen - Thanks a ton for the formatting edit. Was really struggling with it. Would you be kind enough to also help with the solution ? :) Sincerely appreciate the help!

Comment: @TusharSingh yup, working on something now.

Comment: What constitutes a word? Why not "crashes", "works", or "awesome"?

Comment: The list can be expanded. Just wanted to give an idea of what I am trying to do

Comment: @TusharSingh is the solution below what you're looking for? If you're using a data.frame you'll need to convert it to a data.table after loading in the library by running `setDT(yourdataframename)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what we're after. We can call a function that will look for any instance of the word passed to it and count the number of ratings.

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(Content = c("bluetooth is bad", "head unit crashes", "remote workds awesome", "bluetooth is ok..."), Rating = c(1,2,5,3))

> dt
                 Content Rating
1:      bluetooth is bad      1
2:     head unit crashes      2
3: remote workds awesome      5
4:    bluetooth is ok...      3

Count = function(word, dt){

  dt = dt[grepl(word, Content, ignore.case = TRUE), .(Count = .N), by = .(Rating)]
  dt[ , Content := word]
  print(dt)
}
```

Then, we can look at the counts for bluetooth

```
Count("bluetooth", dt)
   Rating Count   Content
1:      1     1 bluetooth
2:      3     1 bluetooth
```

Comment: This is what i got when i ran the code on my system:
     Content Rating

1: bluetooth      1

2: bluetooth      2

3: bluetooth      5

4: bluetooth      3

Comment: @TusharSingh does that seem wrong? I dont have your full dataset

Comment: i actually ran your code as it is. Meaning using your illustrative dataset.

Comment: @TusharSingh do you have data.table installed and loaded? As is should get the same output.

Comment: @TusharSingh 1s theres a typo. sorry!

Comment: Yes, I installed and loaded data.table - that suggested to install dtplyr, i did that, but still the output i am getting is not the same as yours

Comment: @TusharSingh try the updated code. i fixed an issue in the function.

Comment: Yes, that worked now! You! Sir, are a saviour! :)

This was my first question on here, and your answer is a serious motivation to learn R (again!). Thanks a lot!

I will make this in to a function to iterate over a list of words. But i am quite sure I will fail at that, and I am still figuring how to format the comment/question as you do

Comment: @TusharSingh Glad to help! and R is a great language to learn. To format either indent by 4 spaces or select the code button. Just respond if you have a question about the list and i'll see what i can do. Good luck!

Comment: @Frank Why is leaving `TRUE` as `T` not safe?

Comment: OP (or other users later) might define a variable as `T=0L` for example and then try `Count("Bluetooth", dt)`, surprised to see a different result from `Count("bluetooth", dt)`.

Comment: @Kristofersen - Actual dataset has 190 observations in dt (max length for Content is around 150; Ratings are predominantly just 1s). When I run the exact same code, I am getting the following error:

Error in `[.data.frame`(dt, grepl(word, dt$Content, ignore.case = T),  : 
  unused argument (by = .(Rating))

Am i missing something?

My code:

dt <- N365AS[,c("Content","Rating")]

Count = function(word, dt){
  
  dt = dt[grepl(word, dt$Content, ignore.case = T), .(Count = .N), by = .(Rating)]
  dt[ , "Content" := word]
  print(dt)
}

Count("period", dt)

Comment: @TusharSingh you are using a data frame. You need to use a data.table. Set it to a data.table by running `setDT(yourdataframename)`

Comment: @TusharSingh any luck?

Comment: @Kristofersen - Works perfectly now. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Frank